# Why does Entity Framework try to insert existing entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, data-annotations, navigation-properties

I am using Entity Framework (with a code-first approach) and the database is created successfully with the expected foreign keys and unique key constraints.

I have those two model classes:

```
public class Foo 
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Bar Bar { get; set; } 
}

public class Bar
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Index(IsUnique = true), StringLength(512)]
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

And this application code:

```
var foo = GetData();

using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext())
{
    db.Entry(foo).State = EntityState.Added;

    if (foo.Bar != null)
    {
        var bar = await db.Bar.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Url == foo.Bar.Url);

        if (bar != null)
        {
            // When I assign an existing entity ...
            foo.Bar = bar;
        }
    }

    // ... following exception will be thrown.
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

> **SqlException**: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Bar' with unique index 'IX_Url'. The duplicate key value is (https://api.example.com/rest/v1.0/bar/FD6FAB72-DCE2-47DB-885A-424F3D4A70B6).
>   The statement has been terminated.

I don't understand why Entity Framework is trying to add the navigation property `Bar`, even after obtaining and assigning it from the same `DbContext`. Similar StackOverflow questions haven't provided any working solution yet.

Please tell me if I need to provide additional information.

Did I forget to set any EF related configuration or something like that? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because

```
db.Entry(foo).State = EntityState.Added;
```

marks the `foo.Bar` (and any referenced entity not tracked by the context) as `Added` as well.

You should resolve the referenced entities before adding the `Foo` entity:

```
var foo = GetData();
using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext())
{
    // Resolve references
    if (foo.Bar != null)
    {
        var bar = await db.Bar.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Url == foo.Bar.Url);
        if (bar != null)
            foo.Bar = bar;
    }
    // Then add the entity
    db.Entry(foo).State = EntityState.Added;

    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: This resolved my problem. Thank you very much dear friend! =)